# __adobe_cep__.showDevTools() doesn't work since 14.2 update

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

On Photoshop CC 14.0 this code:

```
__adobe_cep__.showDevTools();
```

was showing Chrome Debug console.

On Photoshop CC 14.2, it does not work - nothing happens, no errors reported, console does not show.

What might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though this is a really old question, I want to answer it. I'm new to PS extension development and this question is still the second hit on google.

This debugging mechanism is deprecated now (see [this adobe CC article](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/creativesuite/articles/a-short-guide-to-HTML5-extensions.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0)). The "official" debugging is now *remote debugging*.

You need to enable it by setting the `PlayerDebugMode` in your photoshop preferences to string "1".

Then you place a textfile called `.debug` in your extensions root directory. In this file you put XML to specify your debugging TCP port:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<ExtensionList>
    <Extension Id="com.example.photoshopextension">
        <HostList>
           <Host Name="PHXS" Port="8088"/> 
        </HostList>
    </Extension>
</ExtensionList>
```

Then you can access the tools by opening `http://localhost:8088`.